# How to call a he.js function to decode a JSON output element

Tags: javascript, json

I have included the [he.js file](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) before my closing `</body>` tag.

But I need to call a function to have it decode my JSON output for the `<figcaption>` in a lightbox gallery.

How would I do this? I've tried the following but really not sure what I'm doing.

```
<script>    

    function(he) 
    {
        root.he = he;
    });  

</script>
```

Apologies for the noob question...

[This is the website in question](http://dan-wilton-76aee2b839836203557563f1417b.webflow.io/collections/canyon)

Comment: just follow the documentation https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he#installation

Comment: @RohitHazra I have installed it, I just can't work out how to call it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `he.js` included, you just need to use the `he` variable.

```
<script src="he.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
   console.log(he.version);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: @malloryman see the above way, It's just as in documentation and it works. please try. and mark this answer as accepted if it works. (telling this because you seem to be new here)